# What is the number in a closed box right below a victor airway?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

I see this little number in my TAC.
[image]

What is that "42" inside a box right below v208-458? I looked through charts guide to see if I can find that symbol but I couldn't find anything (pretty sure I missed it). Does it have something to do with victor airway or is it separate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per the [Chart Users Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/) (which covers sectionals *and* TACs), that is the total mileage between navaids.

[image]